# Vscode authorization

Tags: visual-studio-code

Здравствуйте  вылетает ошибка каждую 2-5 минут " Settings sync is suspended because of successive authorization failures. Please sign in again to continue synchronizing "  [image: Settings sync is suspended because of successive authorization failures. Please sign in again to continue synchronizing]

Comment: И всё-таки текст ошибки лучше бы сюда текстом вставить и ситуацию словами описать. Так другим участникам будет проще загуглить это, по крайней мере.

Comment: Settings sync is suspended because of successive authorization failures. Please sign in again to continue synchronizing

Просто не понятно из-за чего это, я несколько раз перезашел все ровно ошибка вылетает

Comment: Говоря "сюда", я имел в виду текст вопроса :) там есть кнопка Править

Comment: да я в гугле уже копал потом сюда написал, просто проблема в том что меня просят чтоб я авторизовался, а я авторизован крч не понимаю что от меня хотят ))

Comment: Мне ясно, в чём проблема. Более того, я сам сталкивался с подобным, а потому хочу, чтобы Вам дали правильный ответ как можно скорее. Это будет возможно, если Вы **внесёте в текст вопроса подробное словесное описание своей проблемы, а также текст ошибки**.

Comment: все все понял не ругайтесь ))